# Ran mix ecto.create, got, Postgrex.Protocol (#PID<0.208.0>) failed to connect: , any suggestions?

Tags: npm, elixir, phoenix-framework

I was trying to create a sample Phoenix application and following the steps at the Phoenix website:

https://hexdocs.pm/phoenix/up_and_running.html.

and when I got to the step for actually creating the Phoenix application (i.e., running "mix phx.new my hello"  It tells me that my password authentication failed and I received these two errors:

> 18:58:13.966 [error] Postgrex.Protocol (#PID<0.334.0>) failed to connect:
> ** (Postgrex.Error) FATAL 28P01 (invalid_password) password
> authentication failed for user "postgres"
>
> 18:58:14.001 [error] Postgrex.Protocol (#PID<0.341.0>) failed to connect:
> ** (Postgrex.Error) FATAL 28P01 (invalid_password)
> password authentication failed for user "postgres"
> ** (Mix) The database for Myhello.Repo couldn't be created: killed

I was expecting it to work, since it is just a sample application, which I assume has been vetted out.  I am probably doing something wrong, but I have uninstalled and reinstalled multiple times now and still keep getting the same exact result.

Comment: "Phoenix assumes that our PostgreSQL database will have a postgres user account with the correct permissions and a password of "postgres". " (From the page you mention) Bad assumption, and poor security but this is the way it is.

Comment: @bortzmeyer it's only the assumption of the default generated config because that's how most developer machines are set up when running against a local database, where security usually isn't a concern.

Answer (score 1):

In the doc you linked, it links to [this](https://hexdocs.pm/phoenix/mix_tasks.html#mix-ecto-create) which has a troubleshooting section that includes the same error message you are seeing.

> If the "postgres" role is using a password different from the default
> "postgres", we'll get this error.
>
> ```
> mix ecto.create
> ** (Mix) The database for Hello.Repo couldn't be created, reason given: psql: FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "postgres"
> ```
>
> To fix this, we can change the password in the environment specific
> configuration file. For the development environment the password used
> can be found at the bottom of the `config/dev.exs` file.

Comment: Excellent!  That did the trick.  Thank you for pointing that out.  I am a bit overwhelmed with all of the tools I have to learn, just to do a GUI.  A lot different from what I am used to, as I've done bare metal drivers for years.  So, I know I have a steep learning curve in front of me and really appreciate your help.